# Spring Cloud Gateway Server between Apache<->Tomcat

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, spring-cloud-gateway

Currently, we provide a service consisting of Apache Web and Tomcat Was.

I would like to use the Spring Cloud Gateway, but I would like to keep the url address used by the existing customer & legacy systems.

So I'm trying to configure Apache Web - Spring Cloud Gateway(spring boot app) - Tomcat Was, but it doesn't work well.

Apache - Tomcat connect with a AJP port.

My question is

1. Can I open the AJP port at Spring Cloud Gateway? Or Is it better to connect with ProxyPass?
2. How can I connect from Spring Cloud Gateway to Tomcat was's AJP port?

my settings are as follows.

[application.yml]

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        health-indicator:
          enabled: false
        simple:
          instances:
            my-gateway-service:
              - uri: dev.gtw01.com:8009
              - uri: dev.gtw02.com:8009
    loadbalancer:
      configurations: health-check
      sticky-session:
        add-service-instance-cookie: true
      cache:
        enabled: false
      health-check:
        path:
          default: /gtw/test
        interval: 10000
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - name: GlobalFilter
          args:
            baseMessage: "Spring Cloud GateWay Global Filter"
            preLogger: true
            postLogger: true
      routes:
        - id: my_gateway
          uri: lb://my-gateway-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/gtw/**
```